# Python Metaclasses are objects?

Tags: python, class, object

Instances are objects created from classes. Classes are objects too, but created from metaclasses. Functions are objects, methods are objects, files are objects, everything in Python is an object.

So metaclasses are also objects?If so, what class do metaclasses belong to?

Comment: Metaclasses are also just classes, which are just objects. It's the relationship of a class to its metaclass that makes the metaclass meta. The metaclass itself isn't anything special.

Comment: in python everything is object :)

Comment: @deceze if I could say in Python,everything is object,except type?